# Hide content for specific users with id

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, shortcode

I want to write a short code so that users who write their id's in it can not see the content of the short code! Example:

```
[hidefrom ids="1,46"]content[/hidefrom]
```

Please help me, I do not know anything about php!

```php
function hidefrom_func($atts, $content = null) {
  global $current_user, $user_login;
  
  if ($user_login)
  extract(shortcode_atts(array('ids' => '1' ), $atts));
  
  $a = wp_get_current_user();
  
  if($a->ID == $ids){

    echo 'access denied!';

  } else {

    return ($content);

  }
}

add_shortcode('hidefrom', 'hidefrom_func');
```

Comment: I would avoid calling this a blacklist, would it not be better to have `[hidefrom ids="1,46"]coontent[/hidefrom]`? It both describes what it does, and avoids problematic naming. Can you update your code so it's indented correctly too? It's very easy to make mistakes and write bugs if everything is on a single line or poorly indented. A good editor can do the indenting for you automatically, give Visual Studio Code or Sublime Text a go if you want a free editor

Comment: You are right! I corrected a little!